# Enable zts on redhat - pthreads on php

Tags: php, pthreads, redhat

I am installing pthreads library on redhat and using it for threading in php.
I successfully installed it on one of the testing servers few months ago.

I have not been able to install it now since

```
   pecl install pthreads
```

needs zts to be enabled first.
I want to know how to enable it so that I may move on to the thread library installation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enable ZTS, I need to download the php source code, will have to enable zts and it needs to be compiled using gcc's make and make install.